# Discord.py - How to run additional code after running client.run(token)?

Tags: discord.py

Seemingly simple question but I'm stuck on how to solve it.

I use discord.py to login to my account and I want to DM a user by inputting his `user_id` .

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')

client = MyClient()
client.run('token')

async def send_message(user_id):
    user = client.get_user(user_id)
    await user.send('My message')
```

When I run this python file in my python shell, it would print the "Logged in as ..." success message and it would hang up. It wouldn't let me type any other command.

I simply want to run the `send_message` function with a unique **user_id**, so I can DM a particular user.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because [client.run](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20run#discord.Client.run) is blocking, so any code below it won't be executed while the bot is running. The best way to avoid this problem is by moving the function somewhere above it, like in the client subclass.

I don't know exactly where you want to execute this function from, so I would suggest that you run it from `on_ready` for now.

```py
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged in as {self.user} (ID: {self.user.id})')

        await self.send_message(123456) # DM a user with id "123456" as soon as the bot is ready

    async def send_message(self, user_id):
        user = self.get_user(user_id)
        await user.send('My message')

client = MyClient()

...
```

If you want to execute this command from Discord, [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html) is a good walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to do is: send a customized message to a list of discord users by their discord ID. This list of users can be in the hundreds of users. Your method works for sending the message, but is there some way for me to send this list of users as a variable or something into `MyClient`, which it can then pass to `self.send_message(...)`?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way. You can use `for loop` to iterate over a list of ids of users and call the function with the id you get from the loop. But be aware that Discord may terminate your account if you're using it to advertise or spam.